# PySpark and argparse

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, command-line-interface, argparse

How does one specify command line arguments using `argparse`  for a PySpark script? I've been breaking my head over this one and I swear I can't find the solution anywhere else.

Here's my test script:

```
import argparse
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--v1", "-a", type=int, default=2)
    parser.add_argument("--v2", "-b", type=int, default=3)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    spark = (SparkSession.builder
        .appName("Test")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    )

    result = args['v1'] + args['v2']
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = main()
    print(result)
```

When I try running the file using `spark-submit file.py --v1 5 --v2 4`, I get an error as shown below:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--v1'
```

However, when I don't specify the arguments (just `spark-submit file.py`), it does the sum correctly, using the default values 2 and 3 from the argument parser, and displays "5" as expected. So clearly it's reading the values from argparse correctly. What's going wrong with the command when I actually pass non-default values?

NOTE: Am using PySpark 2.4.4 and Python 3.6.

EDIT: Of course, I could just use sys.argv and be done with it, but argparse is so much better!

Comment: When debugging `argparse`, it's a good idea to look at `sys.argv` (to see what the shell has provided), and `args` (to see what `argparse` has done with it).  But in your case, I wonder if there's another parser that's also looking at `sys.argv`.  The error does not look like it was generated by your parser.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, that makes sense. I printed out the two, and I get `['path/to/file/file.py']` for sys.argv and `{'v1': 2, 'v2': 3}` from argparse. I wonder whether the issue is related to how I have PySpark set up on my local machine.

Comment: I missed the fact that it is was a `TerminalIPythonApp` that was raising the error.  I don't know how `PySpark` was interacting with `ipython`.  `ipython` does its own parsing, both when called from shell, and when processing its magics.

Comment: Exactly, I missed the fact that it was from the `ipython` side earlier - I'd mistakenly set the python driver environment variable to use `ipython`, which is why argparse didn't work. Thanks for your initial tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `TerminalIPythonApp` error message (similar to [this one](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/issues/243)), Pyspark was trying to pass argparse arguments to *ipython* instead of python. To fix this, set the correct Spark environment as `python3`, not `ipython`.

Add/modify the lines in `/path/to/pyspark/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV="PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3"
```

This ensures that Pyspark looks for the `python3` executable, following which argparse arguments should be read without any issues.